# How to install Python script on XBMC to automatically launch it at startup

Tags: python, installation, autostart, xbmc

I need to install a Python script in XBMC environment to be launched automatically.
The script interacts  with the execution of any video. It works and it is tested.

Now I am looking to find a correct way to install the script by the final user.
The installation must be able to register the script to be launched automatically after the XBMC is started.

I succeded to launch the script automatically putting the following instructions
in the autoeexec.py

```
import os
import xbmc


xbmc.executescript('special://home/scripts/playeractions.py')
```

My script is saved in the   **scripts/playeractions.py** .

I am looking to find the instructions to make a correct installation that will install and register my script for auto launch on XBMC start up.

Comment: From the [XBMC Wiki Manual](http://wiki.xbmc.org/) it sounds like all you'd need to do is either create an [`autoexec.py`](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Autoexec.py) file with those instructions in it or append them to it if the file already exists.

Comment: Yes but where are step by step instructions. There is only a description how to make an Addon (GUI related). I need a service (background script). Somebody needs to take some kind of the installation package and run it. I will need to put the instructions there in the package to append the autoexec.py but how does look like the package if there exist one.

Comment: XMBC is open source software and which means sometimes you have to figure things out and write specialized code to do what you want yourself -- including writing or adding to the collaborative documentation.

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO:_Automatically_start_addons_using_services

Comment: Yes, markdark it is exactly what I need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This page shows you how to start addons using services.

Or refer to the autoexec version above.

http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO:Automatically_start_addons_using_services

Comment: I only added this down here, as it wasn't clear in the comment above.